# Calling a class's static method from a class attribute

Tags: python, oop

I am trying to create a dictionary class attribute that contains string that references to the class's static methods:

```
class Foo:

    references = {
        'string a' : Foo.function_a,
        'string b' : Foo.function_b
    }

    @staticmethod
    def function_a():
        return 0

    @staticmethod
    def function_b():
        return 1
```

The call for Foo from within the class is unresolved:

```
NameError: name 'Foo' is not defined
```

Is there any elegant way to create a class attribute referencing to the class's static methods?

Comment: although i don't understand what you are trying to achieve...but instead of Foo.function_b you should user self.function_b and the function should be defined before the call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Static methods aren't the issue, the problem is that you're trying to refer to methods and classes which aren't defined yet. This works:

```
class Foo:
    @staticmethod
    def function_a():
        return 0

    @staticmethod
    def function_b():
        return 1

    references = {
        'string a' : function_a,
        'string b' : function_b
    }
```

The `class` definition is its own namespace, you can refer to the functions as `function_a` without `Foo`, and you need to do so *after* they have been defined.